# How to stop the timer when the ESC key is pressed

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I'm testing the following add-ons.

This is an add-on that will print 'test' every 0.1 second.

```
import bpy

bl_info = {
    "name": "TestPanel",
    "author": "taichi",
    "version": (1, 0),
    "blender": (2, 80, 0),
    "location": "3DView",
    "description": "test",
    "warning": "",
    "support": "COMMUNITY",
    "wiki_url": "",
    "tracker_url": "",
    "category": "Print"
}

class test_PT_Panel(bpy.types.Panel):
    blidname = "test_PT_Panel"
    bl_label = "test Panel"
    bl_category = "test"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"

    def draw(self,context):
        layout = self.layout

        row = layout.row()
        row.operator('wm.modal_test_operator',text ='TestButton')

class test_OT_Operator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "wm.modal_test_operator"
    bl_label = "Modal test Operator"
    _timer = None
    returnValue = 0.1

    def modal(self, context, event):
        if event.type in {'ESC'}:
            self.cancel(context)
            return{'CANCELLED'}
        return{'PASS_THROUGH'}

    def execute(self, context):

        def printFunction():
            print("test")
            return self.returnValue

        wm = context.window_manager
        bpy.app.timers.register(printFunction)
        wm.modal_handler_add(self)

        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    def cancel(self, context):
        wm = context.window_manager
        self.returnValue = None

classes = (test_PT_Panel,test_OT_Operator)
register,unregister = bpy.utils.register_classes_factory(classes)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

When I press Esc key in the above add-on, I get the following error.

```
line 46, in printFunction
    return self.returnValue

 line 653, in __getattribute__
    properties = StructRNA.path_resolve(self, "properties")
ReferenceError: StructRNA of type test_OT_Operator has been removed
```

I know how to implement Cancel using Timer of ModalOperator, but I don't know how to implement Cancel using normal timer.

I would like to know how to do this without errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to unregister your timer function in the `cancel` method.

To do so I had to bring `printFunction` out of the operator class, because otherwise it needs `self` argument, and I haven't found how to bring it with the function to the timer register operator. So now the idea is to set `returnValue` not as class's instance's variable (using `self.returnValue`), but as class's variable (using `bpy.types.YOUR_OPERATOR_CLASS` instead of `self`) - in `execute`, `cancel`, `printFunction` and any other method or function.

```
import bpy

bl_info = {
    "name": "TestPanel",
    "author": "taichi",
    "version": (1, 0),
    "blender": (2, 80, 0),
    "location": "3DView",
    "description": "test",
    "warning": "",
    "support": "COMMUNITY",
    "wiki_url": "",
    "tracker_url": "",
    "category": "Print"
}

class TEST_PT_Panel(bpy.types.Panel):
    blidname = "TEST_PT_Panel"
    bl_label = "Test Panel"
    bl_category = "test"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"

    def draw(self,context):
        layout = self.layout

        row = layout.row()
        row.operator('wm.modal_test_operator',text ='TestButton')

def printFunction():
    print("test")
    return bpy.types.WM_OT_modal_test_operator.returnValue

class Test_OT_Operator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "wm.modal_test_operator"
    bl_label = "Modal test Operator"
    _timer = None
    returnValue = 0.1

    def modal(self, context, event):
        if event.type in {'ESC'}:
            self.cancel(context)
            return{'CANCELLED'}
        return{'PASS_THROUGH'}

    def execute(self, context):
        bpy.types.WM_OT_modal_test_operator.returnValue = 0.1
        wm = context.window_manager
        bpy.app.timers.register(printFunction)
        wm.modal_handler_add(self)

        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    def cancel(self, context):
        bpy.app.timers.unregister(printFunction)
        bpy.types.WM_OT_modal_test_operator.returnValue = 0


classes = (TEST_PT_Panel,Test_OT_Operator)
register,unregister = bpy.utils.register_classes_factory(classes)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Note that once the variable is changed as class variable it keeps its last meaning even after operator is over. You can for example reset it as class variable in `cancel` method. You can also add for example `set_time: FloatProperty(name="Set Time", default=0.1)` to your Operator class and in the `execute` method set `bpy.types.WM_OT_modal_test_operator.returnValue = self.set_time` - so you could change it at the begining of every launch of your operator, like this: `bpy.ops.wm.modal_test_operator(set_time=0.5)` and also to use this property in ui panel.

**UPDATE:**
Found much easier solution with less changes to your code. Set your `printFunction` to `self._timer` variable and register and unregister `self._timer`

```
import bpy

class TEST_PT_Panel(bpy.types.Panel):
    blidname = "TEST_PT_Panel"
    bl_label = "Test Panel"
    bl_category = "test"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"

    def draw(self,context):
        layout = self.layout

        row = layout.row()
        row.operator('wm.modal_test_operator',text ='TestButton')

class Test_OT_Operator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "wm.modal_test_operator"
    bl_label = "Modal test Operator"
    _timer = None
    returnValue = 0.1

    def modal(self, context, event):
        if event.type in {'ESC'}:
            self.cancel(context)
            return{'CANCELLED'}
        return{'PASS_THROUGH'}

    def execute(self, context):
        def printFunction():
            print("test")
            return self.returnValue
        self._timer = printFunction
        wm = context.window_manager
        bpy.app.timers.register(self._timer)
        wm.modal_handler_add(self)

        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    def cancel(self, context):
        bpy.app.timers.unregister(self._timer)
        self.returnValue = 0


classes = (TEST_PT_Panel,Test_OT_Operator)
register,unregister = bpy.utils.register_classes_factory(classes)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked fine.